# Фазисный глагол

Tags: грамматика

Есть ли здесь фазисные глагол?

> Он хочет учиться рисовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Грамма.ру.**

Академическая Грамматика русского языка считает сочетание "(на)учиться + инфинитив составным глагольным сказуемым. Глагол "(на)учиться" относится к числу "глаголов, имеющих более широкое значение начала, продолжения или завершения действия" (Грамматика русского языка. Т. 2. Синтаксис. Ч. 1. М.: Изд-во АН СССР, 1954. С. 216), иными словами, глагол "научиться" включается в состав фазовых глаголов.
Между тем некоторые лингвисты (например, И.П. Распопов, Е.С. Скобликова и др.) отмечают близость структур "научиться рисовать - научиться рисованию", "привыкнуть отдыхать - привыкнуть к отдыху" и нек. др. и считают на этом основании, что подобные инфинитивные конструкции могут быть рассмотрены как переходные - инфинитив в этом случае может быть квалифицирован как дополнение, а не часть сказуемого. В целом же можно сделать вывод о том, что граница между составными и простыми  сказуемыми не столь очевидна, как об этом обычно говорится в учебной литературе.

Answer (score 0):

Откуда? Фазисные глаголы - глаголы обозначающие некий момент (фазу) действия: начать, закончить, стать, прекратить, продолжить. Ну условно можно причислить еще несколько типа "восстановить", "нарушить". Но не больше.

А у нас типичный модальный глагол "хотеть" и контекстно-модальный глагол "научиться", здесь тоже в роли модального.

Comment: Хотел себя проверить. В книге встретился такой пример в контексте сочетания модальных и фазисных в сказуемых. Опечатка, наверно. (Хотя негоже в таком издании им быть.)

Comment: Ну значит, надо посмотреть трактовку самого понятия "фазисный глагол". Возможно, автор по-другому осмысливает это понятие. Хотя сие есть вещь странная, но всё может быть...

Comment: Да это энциклопедия Караулова; там дальше нормальный идет пример: *Он перестал хотеть учиться рисовать*.

Comment: Так он, наверное, и имел в виду, что этот второй пример - с фазисным глаголом, а первый - для сравнения.